# React/JavaScript Prevent onKeyDown typing (other langs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The reason why I use onKeyDown is the lang for typing is Korean.

I have several inputs and when users type over than 20 bytes, I want to stop them to keep typing.

```
//this calculates bytes
const getByteLength = (s,b,i,c) => {
    for(b=i=0;c=s.charCodeAt(i++);b+=c>>11?3:c>>7?2:1);
    return b;
}
```

.

```
handleLength = (e) => {
    let currentBytes = getByteLength(e.currentTarget.value);
    // checked : it calculates bytes successfully.
    if (currentBytes > 20){
        // checked : This is only working for English. When I type over than 20 bytes, this removes the lastest letter. but I still can type Korean.
        e.currentTarget.value = 
        e.currentTarget.value.substring(0,e.currentTarget.value.length - 1);
    }
}

<input onKeyDown={this.handleLength}>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save the value of your input in a `state` variable:

class Foo extends Component {
    state = {
        value: ''
    };

```
handleLength = (e) => {
    let currentBytes = getByteLength(e.currentTarget.value);
    // checked : it calculates bytes successfully.
    let value = e.currentTarget.value;
    if (currentBytes > 20){
        value = e.currentTarget.value
            .substring(0,e.currentTarget.value.length - 1);
    }
    this.setState({ value });
```

}

And then use the value in the state, in your input:

```
<input value={this.state.value} onKeyDown={this.handleLength} />
```

Comment: I've made a sample code, following your answer.
https://codesandbox.io/s/qk937q1m3j
still, I can keep typing Korean. try to type 홍길동홍길동홍길동 ... I can still type...

Comment: Oops, apparently Korean is considered as 2 bytes. so if i do e.currentTarget.vale.length -2, It works!

Comment: but you're also right. I should've saved the value in the state.